# jquery masked input

Tags: jquery, input

I'm trying to use a masked input with jquery:

How can I input the different phone number in the same textfield?

eg: the first one I want to input 09-99999999 and then another one is 019-9999999 ...

How can I set the symbol "-" at the index 1 n index 2?

Answer (score 0):

Better to receive the input as a number itself, and when the textbox loses focus change it to your desired format.

Check a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ycbZq/)

Comment: And be careful with that "desired format" business, phone numbers in the UK don't look like ones in the US for example.